# Cythonize into a python3.6 wheel on Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04, cython

For legacy reasons, I have a mix of C/C++ and python code that can only be compiled on Ubuntu 14. The python code is compatible with python3.6. We have been generating python3.6 compatible pip wheels for distribution. The pip wheel is generated using python2.7.

We added a new python3.6 module that we need to cythonize.

I have successfully generated a cythonized python2.7 wheel after running

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip install cython
```

To get a python3.6 wheel I tried to do

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

However, that is not supported on Ubuntu14.

I also tried to generate a python3.4 wheel with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo pip3 install cython
```

This fails with

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 155, in get_tag
    assert tag == supported_tags[0]
```

The following are not an option for us :

- Use of non standard repos like thus :

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
- making the entire code base compilable on ubuntu18

How can I get a cythonized python3.6 pip wheel given these constraints ?

Update :
The answer is to build and install python3.6 from source on Ubuntu14 and cythonize as usual using python3.6.

Comment: you kind of need python3.6 to generate a python3.6 wheel, if you can't install it (for instance from deadsnakes) you'd have to build python3.6 from source (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of deadsnakes)

Comment: @AnthonySottile
Thanks. I have not done that before but could probably figure it out. At the same time, I won't mind a pointer/link in the right direction.

Since I am cythonizing on ubuntu14 to run on 16/18, 2 things come to mind :
- are there any gotchas I should be aware off, whereby a compile of python3.6 on 14 is not exactly the same as that on 16/18 and lead to cython output that isn't entirely kosher on 16/18 ?
- does compiling python3.6 on ubuntu14 require different options ? I am worried that might lead to the above and you have probably done this for deadsnakes.

Comment: Actually, my bad.
I did install python3.6 last friday. I just lost track of what I did after the weekend was over. When I  tried it the first time it did not work because I had unwittingly used `make altinstall` instead of `make install`. Once I caught that error it built the cythonized 3.6 just fine. I will be testing it in our test suite to see if any compatability issues crop up. I will update if I see anything

Comment: ~generally building on one platform and running on another while using dynamic linking won't work as they will link different libraries (for example libssl1.0.2 on trusty and libssl1.1 on bionic).  It might work if you don't do any dynamic linking though (and you're going older -> newer)